# How to make a software by tkinter which open full screen in different window resolution

Tags: python, tkinter

How to make a software by python tkinter which open full screen in different window resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear: *opens fullscreen* **or** opens *with a different resolution* **?**

I've given code for both.

---

If you want your `tkinter` window to open in fullscreen:

```
from tkinter import * # importing
root = Tk() # root widget
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True) # make it fullscreen
root.title('Fulscreen Window') # give it a title
root.mainloop() # run mainloop
```

If you want a second `tkinter` window to open with a different resolution:

```
from tkinter import * # importing
root = Tk() # root widget
root.title('First Window') # set title for 1st window
top = Toplevel() # open second window
top.title('Second Window') # name second window
top.geometry('500x500') # resize it (Width x Height)
root.mainloop() # run mainloop
```

---

Explained through comments in code.

Comment: i used '.place(x=0,y=0)' for all entrybox, label and treeview in my code, So how to auto resize when screen resolution has changed?

Comment: @sanjibpoddar you could use `.place(relx=0,rely=0)` . That places them to a location relative to the screen size. `relx` and `rely` have to be between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Comment: And if you want to auto-resize, use `.place(relheight=0,relwidth=0)`. Just remember that `relx`, `rely`, `relheight` and `relwidth` have to be `float`s between 0 and 1.

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
```

This should help

Edited: Please choose this as the Correct Answer if it worked :)